# C++ vector binary I/O

Tags: c++, c++11

Hi: I was trying to write and read a 2D vector in binary mode. But, I am not getting a right output. My C++ code is as follow. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
using namespace std;

int main()
 {
 typedef unsigned  uint;
 typedef complex<double> TYPE;

  uint size=10;
  uint datasize=size*size*sizeof(TYPE);

  vector<vector<TYPE> > X(size, vector<TYPE> (size));

 for(uint i = 0 ; i < X.size() ; ++i ){
 for(uint j = 0 ; j < X.size() ; ++j ){
       X[i][j]={(double)i, (double)j};}}

  for(uint i = 0 ; i < X.size() ; ++i ){
  for(uint j = 0 ; j < X.size() ; ++j ){
   cout << X[i][j] << ' ';}
   cout << std::endl;}

 ofstream o("out.bin",ios_base::binary);
 o.write( (char *)(&X[0][0]), datasize );
 o.clear();
 o.close();


  cout<<"**************************************"<<std::endl;

   vector<vector<TYPE> > Y(size, vector<TYPE> (size));

   streampos begin, end;
   ifstream in("out.bin",ios_base::binary);
   in.read( (char *)(&Y[0][0]), datasize);
   in.clear();
   in.close();

   for(uint i = 0 ; i < Y.size() ; ++i ){
     for(uint j = 0 ; j < Y.size() ; ++j ){
       cout << Y[i][j] << ' ';}
        cout << std::endl;}

    return 0;
    }
```

---

output

```
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5) (0,6) (0,7) (0,8) (0,9) 
(1,0) (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5) (1,6) (1,7) (1,8) (1,9) 
(2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4) (2,5) (2,6) (2,7) (2,8) (2,9) 
(3,0) (3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (3,4) (3,5) (3,6) (3,7) (3,8) (3,9) 
(4,0) (4,1) (4,2) (4,3) (4,4) (4,5) (4,6) (4,7) (4,8) (4,9) 
(5,0) (5,1) (5,2) (5,3) (5,4) (5,5) (5,6) (5,7) (5,8) (5,9) 
(6,0) (6,1) (6,2) (6,3) (6,4) (6,5) (6,6) (6,7) (6,8) (6,9) 
(7,0) (7,1) (7,2) (7,3) (7,4) (7,5) (7,6) (7,7) (7,8) (7,9) 
(8,0) (8,1) (8,2) (8,3) (8,4) (8,5) (8,6) (8,7) (8,8) (8,9) 
(9,0) (9,1) (9,2) (9,3) (9,4) (9,5) (9,6) (9,7) (9,8) (9,9) 
**************************************
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5) (0,6) (0,7) (0,8) (0,9) 
(1,0) (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5) (1,6) (1,7) (1,8) (1,9) 
(2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4) (2,5) (2,6) (2,7) (2,8) (2,9) 
(3,0) (3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (3,4) (3,5) (3,6) (3,7) (3,8) (3,9) 
(4,0) (4,1) (4,2) (4,3) (4,4) (4,5) (4,6) (4,7) (4,8) (4,9) 
(5,0) (5,1) (5,2) (5,3) (5,4) (5,5) (5,6) (5,7) (5,8) (5,9) 
(6,0) (6,1) (6,2) (6,3) (6,4) (6,5) (6,6) (6,7) (6,8) (6,9) 
(7,0) (7,1) (7,2) (7,3) (7,4) (7,5) (7,6) (7,7) (7,8) (7,9) 
(8,0) (8,1) (8,2) (8,3) (8,4) (8,5) (8,6) (8,7) (8,8) (8,9) 
(9,0) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0) (0,0)
```

Comment: Could you share with us what you expected your output to look like?

Comment: Does your program work perfectly if `size < 10`?  If so, for what value of `size` do you get the last "correct" output?  Consider also that when you give a problem statement like *"I am not getting a right output."* that you are asking people who read lots of questions per day to not only read your question, but discern what "right" output would be.  It really helps to make a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us where your debugging road ended because you hit a specific block.  Consider editing your question to demonstrate your own investment in the problem.

Comment: That's never going to work unless you use an actual two dimension array. The `std::vector` stores its data via a pointer that will not be included in your binary output (except by some miraculous accident). But a vector of vectors.....

Comment: @Pinku Nath what you are doing is undefined behavior, like @Galik said. You need to store the 2 dimensional data in a contiguous fashion like `array<array<TYPE,size>,size> X;` for example. Or you can write one vector after the other like `for(auto &vec : X) write((char *)(&vec[0],size*sizeof(TYPE));`

Comment: To be honest I don't know why you are bothering with binary output. Why not just send your `std::cout` to the file and write a function to read it in accordingly?

Comment: Thanks, Galik,PeterT, HostileFork.

Answer (score 3):

Surprising it worked as well as it did - you were lucky in the way the memory of the sub-vectors was allocated.

Instead of

```
o.write( (char *)(&X[0][0]), datasize );
```

and

```
in.read( (char *)(&Y[0][0]), datasize);
```

You'll need to loop over the sub-vectors of X and Y and write/read them separately; e.g.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    o.write( (char *)(&X[i][0]), size*sizeof(TYPE) );
}
```

and

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    o.read( (char *)(&Y[i][0]), size*sizeof(TYPE) );
}
```

Only the sub-vectors have memory that is contiguous. These loops go through the sub-vectors of each "2-D array" and save them in order, and then read them back in order.

Comment: @PinkuNath - You're welcome. If you like, please mark it answered. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 o.write( (char *)(&X[0][0]), datasize );
```

That cast makes no sense. You have to actually assemble the bytes you want to write -- you can't just pretend they're already there.

Comment: Thanks David Schwartz.